# Variable de PHP funciona al hacer echo pero no en query

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un problema y es que estoy intentando ejecutar un código php para obtener información de la base de datos. El problema es que tengo una variable llamada $user_id que si le hago echo, si me muestra el id, pero cuando lo meto en el query no funciona. Es un id numérico.

```php
$user_id = "{{ proposal_seller_id }}";
echo $user_id; //esto si lo muestra
$seleccionar = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id='" . $user_id . "'"); //aquí el user_id es 0
$row = $seleccionar->fetch();
$user_name = $row->user_name;
echo $user_name; // y aquí no muestra nada ya que el query no funciona
```

Muchas gracias y espero que alguien pueda ayudarme.

Comment: Si user_id en la base de datos es un valor numérico, ¿has probado a quitar las comillas simples de la consulta? `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=" . $user_id`

Comment: @RubioRic si, tampoco funciona, es que totalmente ilógico

Comment: Si en vez de $user_id pongo un id, funciona y si hago el echo del user_id funciona, pero si meto el user_id en el query no funciona, no tiene sentido. SOS

Comment: Por favor, muestra el código de la tabla que tienes en sql

Comment: Por favor usa var_dump para depurar tu código y agrega a la pregunta los resultados. Para este caso depura lo siguiente: `var_dump($user_id);`  no queda claro si en tu tabla el criterio debe tener `{{ ... }}` ¿? Depura también esto: `var_dump($row);` y dinos qué muestra. No queda claro que el fetch por defecto sea object para poder leer los resultados en forma de objeto.

Comment: desde mi punto de vista, el problema se debe a que tienes espacios y no estas manejando la variable como numerica, por lo que mysql no encuentra el id... prueba con un cast en la sentencia de mysql